# Remove everything except a certain pattern

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a log file with lots of strings. 
I would like to remove everything from this file (find & replace) except any string that starts with: `phone=` and ended with `Digits=1`

for example: `phone=97212345678&step=1&digits=1`

To find that string I am using `(phone=.*digits=1)` and it works! but I did not manage to find the regex the select everything but this string and to clear them all.

[sample file](http://admin.customee.com/sample.txt).

Comment: What is the language/regex flavor? You can just use something like `.*(phone=\S*?digits=1).*` and replace with `$1`.

Comment: find & replace using notepad++

Comment: So, does `.*(phone=\S*?digits=1).*` to replace with `$1` with *. matches newline* ON works for you?

Comment: partly, it does the job but only in one line. I mean if in a particular line the string exists it remove everything else

Comment: ***. matches newline** ON* - Did you check that option?

Comment: yes. it's now remove everything and keep only the last match.

Comment: :) Please read your question. You asked exactly for that. If not, please update it.

Comment: yes, it finds the a match and remove all the rest but there are more string that match and it keep only the last one. I added a sample file. thanks.

Comment: Good. That means you will have to do that in 2 steps. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In order to remove anything but a specific text, you need to use `.*(text_you_need_to_keep).*` with `.` matching a newline.

In Notepad++, use

**Find**: `.*(phone=\S*?digits=1).*`
**Replace**: `$1`

***NOTE***: **. matches newline** option must be *checked*.

I use `\S*?` instead of `.*` inside the capturing pattern since you only want to match any non-whitespace characters as few as possible from `phone=` up to the closest `digits`. `.*` is too greedy and may stretch across multiple lines with DOTALL option ON.

**UPDATE**

When you want to keep some **multiple** occurrences of a pattern in a text, in  Notepad++, you can use

```
.*?(phone=\S*?digits=1)
```

Replace with `$1\n`. With that, you will *remove all the unwanted substrings but those after the last occurrence of your necessary subpattern*.

You will need to remove the last chunk either manaully or with

```
   FIND: (phone=\S*?digits=1).*
REPLACE: $1
```

Comment: it removes everything and keep only one the last line that mach to:
*(phone=\S*?digits=1).* but there are many more...

Comment: Look, you asked for a regex that *selects everything but this string and to clear them all*. I described the technique and provided a regex that does exactly that: matches all, captures a substring you want to keep, removes all and restores the captured substring with a `$1` backreference. If that is not what you need, explain that in the question. Also, it is a good idea to provide a sample text with a description what went wrong when you applied a specific regex.

Comment: I upated to show what you can do in Notepad++ to "collect" only those subpatterns you want. It is very difficult/inefficient to try and write a regex that matches something else than something if it involves sequences of symbols. Sometimes, it is impossible.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have data like:

> "for execution plan [ID = 7420] at 12/06/2018 08:00:00"

you want to extract just [ID = dddd] part from thousands of lines.
In Notepad++ press ctrl+h open replace window, check regular expression.

Find what:

```
.*?(\[ID = \d+\]).*
```

Replace with:

```
\1
```

For your specific string, regex would be:

```
.*?(phone=.*?digits=1).*
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using some tools like Notepad++ or EditPlus, you may use the following regex replace:

Find string: `^phone=(\d+&step=1&)digits=1`

Replace string: `\1`

Answer (score 0):

### Regex to find the match:

> /^phone=.+&digits=1$/

### To replace file except match:

> /^(?!phone=.+&digits=1$).*/gm

Comment: and replace by what? You just have a matching pattern.