# Deleting everything after matched line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a standard txt file. I want to delete everything after a certain point. 
I have captured everything I want to keep using the following regex:

```
(.+\t\d+\t.+\t\d\t.+\t\d.+)
```

In the txt file, there will be a line that has `Row Count \t` (followed by row count number)

Example: `AB\t1234567890\tStudent Individual Monthly PAID\t1\t.012345\t.012345\tABCD12345678\tFuck Russt\tT-Wayne\t1\t1\tABCD12345678\t0\t123\tEntertainment\tA12342A1234567890A
Row Count\t123456
Abcdefghij Abcd\tAbcdefghij Abcd\tAbcdefgh\tAbc Abcdefg Abcde
AB\tFamily Monthly Gratis Trial\t1234\t0.00
AB\tIndividual Monthly Gratis Trial\t12345\t0.00
AB\tStudent Monthly Gratis Trial\t1234\t0.00
AB\tFamily Introductory OFFER\t123456\t123.45
AB\tIndividual Introductory OFFER\t123456\t1234.56
AB\tStudent Individual Introductory OFFER\t12345\t123.45
AB\tFamily Monthly PAID\t1234567\t12345.67
AB\tIndividual Annual PAID\t12345\t123.45
AB\tIndividual Monthly PAID\t1234567\t12345.67
AB\tStudent Individual Monthly PAID\t123456\t1234.56`

Desired Result: `AB\t1234567890\tStudent Individual Monthly PAID\t1\t.012345\t.012345\tABCD12345678\tFuck Russt\tT-Wayne\t1\t1\tABCD12345678\t0\t300\tEntertainment\tA12342A1234567890A`

I want to delete the 'Row Count' row as well as everything that follows afterwards.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53429744/edit) and add sample text and expected result.

Comment: `(.+\t\d+\t.+\t\d\t.+\t\d.+)` does not match `Row Count 278017`. What did you mean to say? Also, see [Remove everything except a certain pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173575/remove-everything-except-a-certain-pattern/34174118#34174118). If the files are short, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404941/delete-all-content-but-keeping-matched/45405085#45405085) might do what you need.

Comment: Do you want to delete all until the end of the file? Or other limit? And what about everything that is present **before**? Are there linebreak somewhere or is it a single line?

Comment: Is "Find what: `Row Count.+`", "Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`" working for you? Don't forget to check `. matches newline`

Comment: Try `(?s)^Row Count.*`. Are those `\t` TABs or just two char sequences? BTW, if they are tabs you may use your pattern like `(.+\t\d+\t.+\t\d\t.+\t\d.+)\R(?s).*` and replace with `$1`.

Comment: Once it gets to the row containing 'Row Count' i want to delete everything that is after that. Including the line with Row Count itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `(.+\t\d+\t.+\t\d\t.+\t\d.+)` matches the point after which you want to remove everything in the file to its end, you may append `(?s).*` to your pattern and replace with `$1`, a placeholder containing the text captured in the first group.

Do not enable *`.` matches newline* option. `(?s)` will make the next `.` match any chars including line break chars, it is an inline DOTALL modifier variant while the previous ones will still match all chars but line break chars.

[image]

Comment: Thank you all for your help guys. This is perfect!